# Hyperlink to ID - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, anchor

I have a contact div in my home page.

```
<div id="contact">....</div>
```

In my Menu, I have link to #contact that scrolls down smoothly to contact div.

```
<a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
```

While on another page, I have to use

```
<a href="www.mywebsite.com/#contact">
```

While working with wordpress where I have single menu for all pages, can I have both functionalities simultaneously or I have to create 2 different menus, one for home, one for the rest of the pages?

Comment: could you not just have `<a href='/#contact'>Contact...`?

Comment: you can keep only the second one `www.mywebsite.com/#contact` and use some plugin in order to avoid page refresh if the section is already on the page

Comment: @RamRaider This won't work when I am on another page

Comment: @TemaniAfif That seems a good idea. So HTML itself isn't capable of doing that, I have to use plugin?

Comment: @RohailAbbas it should, since `"/#contact"` is a relative url which would essentially resolve to `www.mywebsite.com/#contact` - so you can see how it would still work if you were on another page other than the home page - where this element exists. And you don't have to use a plugin. It would be a better idea to create **x2 links** (menu items) and give them classes that you can use as base selectors to hide/display only on applicable pages. jQuery is also a solution worth exploring since wordpress comes bundled with this library.

Comment: you can do it with HTML and like @UncaughtTypeError described, but since it's a wordpress site i think it's easier to go with a plugin as you will have a lot of good ones ... but if you want to do custom Dev and play with JS/CSS you can also do it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution #1 - interchangeable menu items

**Add x2 menu items:**

1. Select "Screen Options" in the top-right of the screen
2. Select "*CSS Classes*" under **Show advanced menu properties**
3. Add x2 custom links ("*Custom Links* box"), e.g:
   `#contact`
   `/#contact`
4. Once the menu item has been added, click on it to expand it, add a
   custom class in the input field below the label "*CSS Classes
   (optional)*", e.g:
   `anchor-link` for menu item `#contact`
   `internal-link` for menu item `/#contact`

**Declare custom styles:**

```
/* for the home page */
.home .anchor-link {
   display: block; /* or inline-block, whichever is applicable */
}
.home .internal-link {
  display: none; /* hide on home page */
}

/* for every other page */
.anchor-link {
   display: none; /* hide on every other page */
}
.internal-link {
  display: block; /* or inline-block, whichever is applicable */
}
```

*Note: Wordpress has a `body` class for the home page, appropriately called `home` - you can use this as a base selector for any home page specific style rules you need to declare.*

#### Solution #2 - jQuery `.attr()` method

Wordpress links to jQuery CDN libraries, so we can leverage the benefits of jQuery and how it suits the requirements of a situation such as the one we have here.

Using the jQuery `.attr()` method, we can write a script that checks if the element in question, the url is anchoring to, already exists on the page, if it does we remove the preceding forward slash from the url of the menu item to make it an *anchor link* rather than an *internal link*.

**Add the menu item and script:**

1. Follow the methods mentioned in *solution #1* to see how to enable
   *CSS Classes* for menu items - we will need this class as a selector to target with the
   jQuery script
2. Add the menu item as an *internal link* with a *relative url*
   (better to keep it as a link initially since more often than not,
   it'll need to be one - you only have the element with the `id`
   `#contact` on the home page, so the script we are writing will only
   have to run on the home page)
3. Write the script, then add it to your theme files, like the
   `header.php` or `footer.php`*

*Here I would *advise against editing core theme files*, your customisations will be lost with any theme updates, it's also an easy way to wreck a theme if you are not wholly sure what you are doing. I would highly recommend installing a plugin for these customisations, a plugin like "**Insert Headers & Footers**" by *WP Beginner* will work perfectly, you should also find this plugin useful for future customisations of this nature and not only applicable for this "once-off use-case" - about the only time you will find me advocating the use of a plugin, otherwise it's just code bloat and another addon to maintain.

**The jQuery script:**

*Untested but should suffice to demonstrate the intention*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(jQuery('#contact').length) { /* if '#contact' exists length will be greater than 0 */
    /* update the href attribute for the anchor link in question */
    jQuery('.dynamic-link a').attr('href','#contact'); 
  }
});
```

The above script will run when the document is ready to check if the element with the `id` "*contact*" already exists on the page, if it does, it'll update the `href` attribute on the menu item we added the custom class to (`.dynamic-link`). Note that this custom class is added to the *list item* (`li`) and not the nested anchor link (`a`).

Answer (score 2):

Add custom link as,`<a href="www.mywebsite.com#contact">`

in your custom jquery add

```
//jQuery for Page Scroll - Single page      
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 500);
                return false;
            }
    }
});



// jQuery for Page Navigation
$( window ).load(function() {

            if(window.location.hash) {
                var url=window.location.href;
                var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')+1);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#"+hash).offset().top
                }, 1000);   
            }  
});
```